# Ordering results within a CONCAT string

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table of new and used cars:

```
id  country     status  car
1   Australia   new     Honda
2   Australia   used    Alfa Romeo
3   Australia   used    Jaguar
4   Australia   used    BMW
5   Belgium     new     BMW
6   Belgium     new     Citroen
7   Belgium     used    Honda
```

I would like to count the number of each used and new car per country, then display the results like this:

```
country     new                    used 
Australia   1 new: Honda           3 used including Alfa Romeo  
Belgium     2 new including BMW    1 used: Honda
```

In other words, if there is more than one 'new' or 'used' per country, to concat them into a string with the *first* car name (by id, which is prioritized).

This is my code:

```
SELECT t1.country, 
CASE 
    WHEN LENGTH(group_concat(t1.status)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(group_concat(t1.status), "new", "")) = 1 THEN CONCAT("1 new: ", t1.car)
    WHEN LENGTH(group_concat(t1.status)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(group_concat(t1.status), "new", "")) > 1 THEN CONCAT(LENGTH(group_concat(t1.status)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(group_concat(t1.status), "new", "")), " new including ", t1.car)
    ELSE ''
END as new, 
CASE 
    WHEN LENGTH(group_concat(t1.status)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(group_concat(t1.status), "used", "")) = 1 THEN CONCAT("1 used: ", t1.car)
    WHEN LENGTH(group_concat(t1.status)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(group_concat(t1.status), "used", "")) > 1 THEN CONCAT(LENGTH(group_concat(t1.status)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(group_concat(t1.status), "used", "")), " used including ", t1.car)
    ELSE ''
END as noms
from table1 t1
group by t1.country
```

However, these are my results:

```
country     new                        used 
Australia   1 new: Honda               3 used including Honda
Belgium     2 new including BMW        1 used: BMW
```

In these results, if there is more than one 'new' or 'used' per country, it is simply showing me the *first* car, irrespective of the status.

How can I get it to show me the *first car per status* if there are multiple results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this query [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12796/1).

```sql
SELECT country,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(IF(status = 'new', id, NULL)) = 1 THEN CONCAT('1 new: ', GROUP_CONCAT(IF(status = 'new', car, NULL)))
    WHEN COUNT(IF(status = 'new', id, NULL)) > 0 THEN CONCAT(COUNT(IF(status = 'new', id, NULL)), ' new including ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(status = 'new', car, NULL) ORDER BY id SEPARATOR ';'), ';', 1))
    ELSE 'no new cars'
  END AS new_cars,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(IF(status = 'used', id, NULL)) = 1 THEN CONCAT('1 used: ', GROUP_CONCAT(IF(status = 'used', car, NULL)))
    WHEN COUNT(IF(status = 'used', id, NULL)) > 0 THEN CONCAT(COUNT(IF(status = 'used', id, NULL)), ' used including ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(status = 'used', car, NULL) ORDER BY id SEPARATOR ';'), ';', 1))
    ELSE 'no used cars'
  END AS used_cars
FROM cars
GROUP BY country
```

You can use `ORDER BY` and `SEPARATOR` in [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Need first car by id? Use `ORDER BY id` with [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) with proper separator to extract first car.